# How to prove Positive Definite with following matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have trouble with proving the following.

> P is $m \times m$ positive definite and diagonal matrix. Q and R are $ n \times m $ matrices that $n < m$. Q and R have full rank, but $ Q \neq cR $ for any real number $c$. The elements of Q and R are not 0.

Let, $ S = QPQ^T - QPR^T (RPR^T)^{-1}RPQ^T $

I found out that S is always positive semi-definite with Matlab simulation, but I couldn't prove it analytically. Moreover, there are interesting properties which are,

> If $ 2n \leq m$, S is always positive definite. (Not semi-definite)

These are all from numerical results, so I don't have confidence that these are true. How can I prove it mathemetically?

Comment: Observation: if we take $B = QP^{1/2}$ and $C = RP^{1/2}$, then we can rewrite your matrix as
$$
S = B[I - C^T(CC^T)^{-1}C]B^T = B[I - C^+C]B^T,
$$
where $C^+$ denotes the (Moore Penrose) pseudoinverse of $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $S$ is of the form $A - X B^{-1} X^T$, i.e., it is the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of the symmetric block matrix
$$
Z=\begin{pmatrix} Q P Q^T & Q P R^T \\ R P Q^T & R P R^T \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now we know that as $P$ is positive definite and $R$ has full rank that $RPR^T$ is positive definite. Under this condition there's a result that says that $S\geq 0$ iff the block matrix $Z \geq 0$. (Note that there are several other possibilities -- see the bottom of the linked wiki page). So our problem reduces to showing $Z \geq 0$. However, note that
$$
Z = 
\begin{pmatrix} Q P Q^T & Q P R^T \\ R P Q^T & R P R^T \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} Q \\ R \end{pmatrix} P \begin{pmatrix} Q^T & R^T \end{pmatrix} = M P M^T
$$
where $M = \begin{pmatrix} Q \\ R\end{pmatrix}$. But as $P$ is positive definite we have $MPM^T$ is positive semidefinite and the result holds.

Comment: This also leads to an answer regarding the second result. We have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(Z) = \operatorname{rank}(S) + \operatorname{rank}(RPR^T),
$$
and we see that $S$ is (strictly) positive definite if and only if it has the maximal possible rank of $n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for that addition.

Comment: @Rammus Thanks!! I understand the proof, still, need to study about Schur complement more.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks, too!! I couldn't perfectly understand with second proof, but this will help me a lot.